# Estimating "population p-value" $\Pi$ using an observed p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, p-value

I asked [a similar question last month](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254595), but from the responses, I see how the question can be asked more precisely.

Let's suppose a population of the form

$$X \sim \mathcal{N}(100 + t_{n-1} \times \sigma / \sqrt{n}, \sigma)$$

in which $t_{n-1}$ is the student $t$ quantile based on a specific value of a parameter $\Pi$ ($0<\Pi<1)$. For the sake of the illustration, we could suppose that $\Pi$ is 0.025.

When performing a one-sided $t$ test of the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu = 100$ on a sample taken from that population, the expected $p$ value is $\Pi$, irrespective of sample size (as long as simple randomized sampling is used).

I have 4 questions:

1. Is the $p$ value a maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of $\Pi$? (Conjecture: yes, because it is based on a $t$ statistic which is based on a likelihood ratio test);
2. Is the $p$ value a biased estimator of $\Pi$? (Conjecture: yes because (i) MLE tend to be biased, and (2) based on simulations, I noted that the *median* value of many $p$s is close to $\Pi$ but the *mean* value of many $p$s is much larger);
3. Is the $p$ value a minimum variance estimate of $\Pi$? (Conjecture: yes in the asymptotic case but no guarantee for a given sample size)
4. Can we get a confidence interval around a given $p$ value by using the confidence interval of the observed $t$ value (this is done using the non-central student $t$ distribution with degree of freedom $n-1$ and non-centrality parameter $t$) and computing the $p$ values of the lower and upper bound $t$ values? (Conjecture: yes because both the non-central student $t$ quantiles and the $p$ values of a one-sided test are continuous increasing functions)

Comment: Out of curiosity, based upon your simulations, does $\hat{p}$ maintain a constant distribution, and if so, what distribution best models the results of $\hat{p}$?  I'm also curious if the distribution parameters for $\hat{p}$ can be determined from the data used for the $t$-test and/or the $t$-test.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found a possible answer for you.

In *Computational Statistics Handbook with MATLAB* by Wendy L. Martinez and Angel R. Martinez, they state:

> Let $\theta$ represent a population parameter that we wish to estimate, and let $T$ denote a statistic that we will use as a point estimate for $\theta$.  The observed value of the statistic is denoted as $\hat{\theta}$.  An interval estimate for $\theta$ will be of the form $$\hat{\theta_{Lo}}<\theta<\hat{\theta_{Up}}$$ where $\hat{\theta_{Lo}}$ and $\hat{\theta_{Up}}$ depend on the observed value $\hat{\theta}$ and the distribution of the statistic $T$.
>
> If we know the sampling distribution of $T$, then we are able to determine values for $\hat{\theta_{Lo}}$ and $\hat{\theta_{Up}}$ such that $$P\left(\hat{\theta_{Lo}}<\theta<\hat{\theta_{Up}}\right)=1-\alpha$$ where $0<\alpha<1$. [The preceding equation] indicates that we have a probability of $1-\alpha$ that we will select a random sample that produces and interval that contains $\theta$.  [$\hat{\theta_{Lo}}<\theta<\hat{\theta_{Up}}$] is called a $\left(1-\alpha\right)\cdot100\%$ confidence interval. \dots It should be noted that one-sided confidence intervals can be defined similarly [Mood, Graybill and Boes, 1974].
>
> $\dots$
>
> the procedure for Monte Carlo hypothesis testing using the $p$-value approach is similar.  Instead of finding the critical value from the simulated distribution of the test statistic, we use it to estimate the $p$-value.
>
> ## Procedure—Monte Carlo Hypothesis Testing (P-Value)
>
> 1. For a random sample of size $n$ to be used in a statistical hypothesis test, calculate the observed value of the test statistic $t_0$.
> 2. Decide on a pseudo-population that reflects the characteristics of the population under the null hypothesis.
> 3. Obtain a random sample of size $n$ from the pseudo-population.
> 4. Calculate the value of the test statistic using the random sample in step 3 and record it as $t_i$.
> 5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for $M$ trials.  We now have values $t_i=1,\dots,t_M$, that serve as an estimate of the distribution of the test statistic, $T$, when the null hypothesis is true.
> 6. Estimate the $p$-value using the distribution $\dots$, using the following.
>
> *Lower Tail Test*$$\hat{p}-value=\frac{\left(t_i\leq t_0\right)}{M}$$ for $i=1,\dots,M$
>
> *UpperTail Test*$$\hat{p}-value=\frac{\left(t_i\geq t_0\right)}{M}$$ for $i=1,\dots,M$

It seems reasonable then, that you could use this same method to report the limits of the sampled $p$-values in some meaningful way to represent a confidence interval of the test statistic.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51304/confidence-interval-on-a-p-value also references a `R` package which reports the confidence interval for a $p$-value.

Comment: Thanks for the research. It is exactly what I did in the second sub-point of point 2. in my question above. However, it does not answer any of my questions. Is this approach a biased estimate of $\Pi$? Is it a minimum variance estimate of $\Pi$? Here, because I know the sampling distribution of the statistic $\theta$, can I use the noncentral t distribution to get bounds instead of a simulation as suggested in your response?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know.  I stumbled across this information while looking for some completely different information in the book.  The book really didn't elaborate beyond what is shown here, it simply covered that this *could* be done and provided the above information as an example. It does seem to point to your fourth conjecture, as the Mote Carlo simulation isn't predicting $\Pi$ or the confidence interval for $\hat{p}$ as much as it is providing a means of a confidence interval for the $t$-test, using the conversion to $p$-values to make the results of the test intuitively meaningful.